# hasNext() method in array iterator

Tags: c++, arrays, generics, iterator

that is my generic Array header file:

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H
#include "Number.h"
#include "Iterator.h"

//array is contius memory of numbers
class Array{
protected:
    //array has some contius cell of memory each include the data
    class Cell{
    public:
        Number* m_data;

        //c'tor:(inline)
        Cell(Number* num=NULL): m_data(num){};
        //D'tor (inline)
        ~Cell(){};
    };
    //composition class of iterator:
    class ArrayIterator:public Iterator{
    public:
        Cell* m_current;

        //C'tor:(inline)
        ArrayIterator(Cell* cell):m_current(cell){};
        //D'tor:
        ~ArrayIterator(){};

        //is there any next numbers
        bool hasNext()const;
        //is there any prev numbers
        bool hasPrev()const;

        //returning the current and getforward
        Number& next();
        //returning the current and getback
        Number& prev();

    };
    Cell* m_head,*m_last;
public:
    //C'tor:
    Array(const int amount);
    //D'tor:
    virtual ~Array(){delete[]m_head;};


    //Random access operator:
    Number& operator [] (const int i)const{return *m_head[i].m_data;};


};


#endif
```

consider Number and Iterator as abstract classes and Number represent a generic number.

my question: how to implement hasNext() in ArrayIterator, because the ArrayIterator is a composition class and it dont "know" the size of the array

Comment: You should pass the end to the iterator or mark the end with a special Number.

Comment: This is why in the C++ Standard library you have no `hasNext` but only `my_iterator != end` (where `end` is another iterator, e.g. pointing to `m_last+1`).

Comment: hansmaad- do you mean making new attribute of size in the iterator? that may solve the problem but making the memory bigger, also that the iterator goes by specific cell that it dont know the place of that specific cell

Comment: You'll find that C++ programmers are confused by Java-style iterators, just as Java programmers are confused by C++-style iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement the `hasNext()` and `hasPrev()` methods, the `ArrayIterator` needs to know where the bounds are of the current `Array` it is iterating over.

This can be done by either storing `Cell* m_head,*m_last` along with `m_current` in the `ArrayIterator`, or by storing a pointer to the `Array` object and arranging that the `ArrayIterator` has access to the `m_head` and `m_last` of the `Array` object. In either case, you need to store additional information in the `ArrayIterator`.